# Python: Why do is the traceback getting printed?

Tags: python

I have a function. The function get started in some more threads. I tried to print a own error message. But its not important what I do I get still the traceback printed. My function:

```
def getSuggestengineResultForThree(suggestengine, seed, dynamoDBLocation):
    results[seed][suggestengine] = getsuggestsforsearchengine(seed, suggestengine)

    for keyword_result in results[seed][suggestengine]:
        o = 0
        while True:
            try:
                allKeywords.put_item(
                    Item={
                        'keyword': keyword_result
                    }
                )
                break
            except ProvisionedThroughputExceededException as pe:
                if (o > 9):
                    addtoerrortable(keyword_result)
                    print('ProvisionedThroughputExceededException 10 times in getSuggestengineResultForThree for allKeywords')
                    break
                sleep(1)
                o = o + 1
                print("ProvisionedThroughputExceededException in getSugestengineResult")
```

But I get for every Thread an output like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-562:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/iTom/ownCloud/Documents/Workspace/PyCharm/Keywords/TesterWithDB.py", line 362, in getSuggestengineResultForThree
'keyword': keyword_result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 518, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 252, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 542, in _make_api_call
raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the PutItem operation: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API
```

Can someone help me to get my own print instead of the traceback? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` is not actually the error. Try:

```
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as pe:
```

instead.

If that doesn't work, figure out what line the error is occurring on and put the `except` statement there.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late for your question but here it is in case anyone is searching for this answer.

The exception that boto3 throws is a `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` as Neil has answered. However you should check response error code for 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException' because the `ClientError` could be for another issue.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

except ClientError as e:
  if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException':
    raise
  # do something else with 'e'
```

I am using Python 2.7 which may or may not make a difference. The exception that I receive suggests that boto3 is already doing retries (up to 9 times) which is different from your exception:

> An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the PutItem operation (reached max retries: 9): The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.